# Setting fill-color in XSSFCell with Apache POI does not work

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was trying to execute the following test (mainly copied from the [Apache POI homepage](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills)) to verify the API was working correctly. The test doesn't throw an exception, but when I look at the produced Excel file the colored cell (0,0 = A1) is in fact plain white. No color applied. The cell value has been set correctly.

I am using `POI 3.9-20121203 (stable)`.

What am I missing here? Why does the example not work as expected?

```
@Test
public void test() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell( 0);
    cell.setCellValue("custom XSSF colors");

    XSSFCellStyle style1 = wb.createCellStyle();
    style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128)));
    style1.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    File f = new File("test.xlsx");     
    f.delete();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);     
    wb.write(fos);      
    fos.close();        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the `XSSFCellStyle`, but you forgot to assign it to a cell, with [`Cell`'s `setCellStyle`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellStyle%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle%29) method.

```
cell.setCellStyle(style1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another point you have to pay attention to when operating on existing Excel files and which could make setting cell styles not work properly: you always have to compare the CellStyle obtained from the Cell with the default CellStyle of the Sheet. And if both are equal you need to create a new CellStyle from the workbook.

*Assigning a new color to the default CellStyle will not produce any visible change in your Excel sheet.*

The correct way of assigning a color to your cell without overwriting previous styles would be this:

```
// get cell style
XSSFCellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();

// get default workbook style
XSSFCellStyle defaultStyle = workbook.getCellStyleAt((short) 0)

// if both are equals create new style in workbook
if(style.equals(defaultStyle)) {
    style = workbook.createCellStyle();     
}

// assign color
style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(myColor));
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

// set style
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue with the XSSFCellStyle copying.

In my case I have multiple xlsx input stream objects creating the individual xlsx files. However I need single xlsx file with all the xlsx input streams are individual sheets in that single xlsx file.

I faced two challenges with POI-3.11 version.
1) When duplicate merge regions are adding to the single sheet the xlsx file generating with some issue. Whenever I tried to open the file it is asking for the recovery of the file.

This issue resolved by adding merge region only once.

2) Issue with the background color copy.
Some fields in the final xlsx file are populating with the wrong background color from the source file.

This issue resolved by copying the source style to destination for every cell. I faced issue when I tried to consolidate the list of different styles available in the source sheet and comparing the source cell style with the list.

Hope this will help.